# Shorthand for >= and < in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

`BETWEEN` clause in mysql is the shorthand for `>= AND <=`.
But if I want to make a comparison of the form `>= AND <` is there a shorthand notation for it in mysql?

Comment: Probably not... it's also very hard to imagine what it would look like (and still be *shorter* than `>= AND <`)

Comment: No. There is no shorthand.If there was, it would also require a separate shorthand for `> AND <=`

Comment: @Pekka. It would look like  `x BETWEEN_LT a AND b`, where it specifies and operation like "between", but with a "less than" comparison at the high end of the range, instead of a "less than or equal to".  This would be convenient for range checks on DATETIME expressions, where we want all values in a given month, or a given day, etc. (A corollary operator such as BETWEEN_GT could also be available, as short hand for `a < x <= b`, but it wouldn't be strictly necessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no builtin shorthand for the general case.

To do a `>= and <` range comparison, there's no getting around specifying the expression twice.

---

It would be possible to create a user-defined function that takes three arguments, and returns 0, 1 or NULL. But that's an extra database object, it hides what's happening... so, we don't want to go there.